# Button function. How to close an application

Tags: android, button

I wanted to create an illuminated button which closes my application, firstly(when it was basic not illuminated button) I tried to finish my app using finish(); but now it doesn't work, because when I places it somewhere in code it doesn't work, I don't know why. Maybe this function doesn't work for the all project ??

```
settings.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.set tings_button)); 
    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View button) {
        if (button.isSelected()){
            button.setSelected(false);
        }
        else {
            button.setSelected(true);            

        }       

    }

finish();

     });
```

I tried with systemexit and finish(); what I should do and where I should place one of the exit commands to finish my app ?

PS. Yes, I`ve read other similar topics but, there problem was much more complicated than mine.

Comment: That code above shouldn't compile. So wonder if he copied wrong, or really has this code in his project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: finish() is in bad place but only here, in code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put finish inside the onClick:

```
settings.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.set tings_button)); 
    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View button) {
        if (button.isSelected()){
            button.setSelected(false);
        }
        else {
            button.setSelected(true);            
        }       
        finish();
    }
     });
```